# What's with this SQL 'With' clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This SQL function below can be used to generate numbers between the low and high.
I sort of understand how it is working, but I can't wrap my head around a couple things.
First the WITH Clause. This doesn't follow the CTE construct. It's not a CTE, right? What is this syntax?

The L0-l5 and Nums are all tables but I don't understand the  'L0 as' syntax. You can't declare a table that right way,right? Can I do that outside of a function?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNums](@low AS BIGINT, @high AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN
    WITH
        L0   AS (SELECT c FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1) AS D(c)),
        L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
        L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
        L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
        L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
        L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
        Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum FROM L5)
        SELECT TOP(@high - @low + 1) @low + rownum - 1 AS n  FROM Nums  ORDER BY rownum;
```

Comment: "This doesn't follow the CTE construct" - in what way?

Comment: Right it does, I realize my mistake now but I have never seen it with it being used to define multiple tables. All examples I have seen it was just with 1 table.  A bit of a brain fart I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about CTEs. They are defined with a WITH statement and their definitions are comma separated.

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> WITH expression_name [ ( column_name [,...n] ) ]
>
> AS
>
> ( CTE_query_definition )

Comment: The question *mentions* CTEs. Twice. I think it's unlikely that the OP has never heard of them. That's why I'm struggling to understand the question.

Comment: He is asking if the WITH follows the CTE constract and what is the CTE syntax.

Comment: No, they state, **twice** that they don't believe that this **is** a CTE.

Comment: And i have quoted a CTE syntax and added a link to the relative article that points out that this is actually the syntax. What haven't i understand well?

Comment: The OP is obviously aware of CTEs. They're also obviously aware that `WITH` clauses are involved with CTEs (otherwise I doubt that they'd have linked the two concepts). Despite this, they've looked at code that runs `WITH Name as (...)` and concluded, for some reason, that it's not a CTE.

Comment: Yes CTE I am familiar with but didn't realize one could define multiple tables. Now looking at it again I see the my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a whole different approach too:

```
DECLARE @i integer = 0
DECLARE @l integer = 0
DECLARE @h integer = 100
DECLARE @output integer
DECLARE @mytable table (m_output int)

WHILE (@i >= @l AND @i < @h)
BEGIN
SET @output = @i
INSERT INTO @mytable(m_output) VALUES(@output);
SET @i = @i + 1;
END

SELECT * FROM @mytable;
```